# Error system services exception vagrant up virtual box windows 10

Tags: laravel, vagrant, virtualbox, homestead

I have virtual box Versión 5.1.30 r118389 (Qt5.6.2); vagrant 2.0.1 and laravel/homestead 5.01, when i do vagrant up show message error:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Do you have hardware virtualization (VT-x) enabled in your BIOS? You need to ensure you do NOT have Hyper-V enabled.

Outside of that you'd have to investigate that stop code to see what Windows was doing when the crash happened.

Comment: Thank you very much for answering, if it is enabled the virtualization, its very stranger